Coordinator Layout: Bottom Navigation Bar gets shrinked
I'm using a Coordinator Layout with fitsSystemWindow= true.
This is needed to make use of the material3 behavior that during scrolling the statusbar and the toolbar gets colored in the same way with an primaryish color accent. And this feature I really love and want to keep.
Layout also includes AppBarLayout with a Toolbar.
Below that is a FrameLayout which hosts all of my fragments inside.
In addition a BottomNavigation View is displayed and placed at the bottom of the Coordinator Layout with gravit= bottom.
The result is all fine if I have navigation via gestures enabled.
But if I activate navigation via 3dots menu, the Bottom Navigation view gets shrinked:

How can I avoid that happening?
I'm using material3 library, still with xml layouts..
